# HTML parsing not happening for "<" but happening for ">"

Tags: html, parsing

I have an application where in I have to parse the html content

```
<html><body>
<html><body><html><body>
<html><body><font color=gray>/ns0:messType1/ItTransaction/items/<font color=blue>
<b>e1</b><font color=black>=<html><body><font color=#808000><b>const</b></font>(value=>)
<br><html><body><font color=gray>/ns0:messType1/ItTransaction/items/<font color=blue>
<b>e2</b><font color=black>=<html><body><font color=#808000><b>const</b></font>(value=<)
<br></html></body>
</html></body></html></body>
</html></body>
```

while parsing the above html document using a method `getEditorKit().read(new StringReader(str), doc, 0);` then it is return empty string for `<` value but for `>` it is returning appopriate value as `>`.

Why is that happening and how can I get the `<` also which I am passing in the value field?

Comment: This is very invalid HTML, were you aware of that?

Comment: the may be the html is invalid ,but my query is how to get the value "<".

Comment: @Gareth - I dunno...that looks like some pretty [strong web design](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Strong-Web-Design.aspx) to me!

Comment: Let's start with this: This is not an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside that the given HTML is beyond invalid, the issue is that `<` is a special character in HTML, denoting the start of a tag. `&lt;` is the proper way to encode a `<` in HTML.

Of course, that's assuming you have control over the HTML content you're handling. If you don't, it may be quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: So if I am getting you rite ,U mean that instead of passing value=<I must pass value = &lt??.

Comment: `&lt;`, yes. Don't forget the semicolon! `&lt;` and things like it are called *entities*, and are how you escape special and untypable characters. It's comparable to how you use `\"` in a string literal in Java.

Comment: But the same logic is not applicable for ">" why we doint have to give "&gt;" for ">".

Comment: Because `>` *ends* a tag. But in the code above, you can't end something you haven't started yet. You might want &gt; if you were going to rely on something like `<img src=arrow.jpg alt=&gt;>`, though.

Comment: @vsaraogi Am I to understand that you generate this "html" yourself?

Comment: @vsaraogi: No problem! If my answer solved your problem, you might want to consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark next to it. :)